# Set back to original uilayoutconstraint - zoom in animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout, constraints

Using a Storyboard, I have a height constraint with 2 size class (one for regular at 200pt, one for compact at 100pt).

Because I'm animating it when the view appears, the height of the element goes from 0 (initial state) -> 200pt for regular or 100pt for compact (final state).

It is a simple "zoomIn" animation.

But the thing is that because I change programmatically the constant, I'm losing the class sizes meaning when I rotate the phone, I have to set the constant to the right size instead of having Interface Builder's automatic class size.

So how would you apply an animation to an UIElement with auto-layout (and without having to create spaghetti code in viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews)?

Answer (score 1):

Without your code, it's not clear exactly what you're doing, but here goes anyway :) First, the best way to animate when you are using autolayout is to animate the constraint changes, e.g.:

```
myConstraint.constant = myConstraintInitialConstant
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationSpeed) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The most important thing to note here is that the constraint change is **outside** the animation block, what you animate is layoutIfNeeded().

But you want to know what your initial constant was when the nib was loaded, yes? Then save it in viewDidLoad(), e.g.:

```
private var myConstraintInitialConstant: CGFloat = 65

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myConstraintInitialConstant = myConstraint.constant
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the different constants because I have a different one for Regular and Compact? And I can only get the current one in use.

Comment: perhaps look at overriding `traitCollectionDidChange:`? Sorry, I have never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to play with the layoutIfNeeded() / layoutSubviews() methods ? This will update the frame of your UIElement after added new constraints to it

I had a top constraint set to 0 and I animate it like that :

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // I reset my constraint's constant if already animate
        if(topConst.constant > 0){
            topConst.constant = 0
        }

        self.viewToAnimate.layoutIfNeeded()

    //Animate the constraint
            topConst.constant = 100
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.viewToAnimate.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
        }
```

I used layoutSubviews it works fine :D